How can I select by latitude / longitude for a NetCDF dataset when these are given as Coordinates (not Dimensions)?
I am working with NetCDF data. The dimensions for the Xarray dataset are given as "x", "y", "time" and the coordinates are "lon" (y,x) "lat" (x,y) and "time".
I want to find the value for a variable "temperature" at a specific lat, lon, time.

Is it possible to use sel for this? (I know how to do this if lat/lon were the dimensions ... but not when given coordinates).
ds.temp.sel(time='2018-01-01', lat=-59.71, lon=89.9).values

Also, what is the (x,y) in parenthesis telling me (and why x AND y if each of these refer to either lat or lon)?


I have seen suggestions to regrid data but not sure how this helps. Also, have seen documentation on multidimensional coordinates, and mapping data. However, these don't answer the question (https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/examples/multidimensional-coords.html)
ds.tas_ymonmean.sel(time=time, x=lat, y=lon).values #TypeError: invalid indexer array, does not have integer dtype: array(-8.229)

Here are the outputs from NCO dump:
dimensions:
    x = 1000 ;
    y = 950 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (12 currently)
variables:
    float lon(y, x) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
    float lat(y, x) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat" ;
    double height ;
        height:standard_name = "height" ;
        height:long_name = "height" ;
        height:units = "m" ;
        height:positive = "up" ;
        height:axis = "Z" ;
    double time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "days since 1949-12-01 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "360_day" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
    float tas_ymonmean(time, y, x) ;
        tas_ymonmean:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
        tas_ymonmean:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
        tas_ymonmean:standard_name = "mean_temperature_index_per_time_period" ;
        tas_ymonmean:long_name = "mean air temperature (seasonality)" ;
        tas_ymonmean:units = "Degree Celsius" ;
        tas_ymonmean:cell_methods = "time:mean" ;
        tas_ymonmean:associated_files = "-" ;
        tas_ymonmean:cell_measures = "area:areacella" ;
        tas_ymonmean:history = "-" ;
        tas_ymonmean:title = "Mean monthly temperature" ;
        tas_ymonmean:coordinates = "lat lon height" ;
        tas_ymonmean:variable = "tas_ymonmean" ;

// global attributes:
        :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.8.2 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
        :experiment = "Historical run" ;
        :experiment_id = "historical" ;
        :realization = "1" ;
        :driving_experiment = "MOHC-HadGEM2-ES,historical,r1i1p1" ;
        :driving_model_id = "MOHC-HadGEM2-ES" ;
        :driving_model_ensemble_member = "r1i1p1" ;
        :driving_experiment_name = "historical" ;
        :model_id = "KNMI-RACMO22E" ;
        :rcm_version_id = "v2" ;
        :CORDEX_domain = "EUR-11" ;
        :product = "output" ;
        :frequency = "day" ;
        :knmi_global_comment = "HadGEM2-ES forced RACMO2 simulation with corrected latitudinal SST-remapping" ;
        :knmi_model_comment = "RACMO22E: baseline physics from ECMWF CY31r1; modifications include HTESSEL CY33r1, patch K-diffusion CY32r3, moist Turbulent Kinetic Energy, satellite inferred Leaf Area Index" ;
        :knmi_version_comment = "v2: replaces withdrawn results with RCMVersionID = v1 (this applies only to HadGEM2-ES forced RACMO2 simulations)" ;
        :knmi_grib_path = "mos.knmi.nl:/climreg/CXEUR12/eSSTcorr-v496-fHadGEM2-r1i1p1+hist/GRIB_data" ;
        :tracking_id = "82a803d5-e106-4f6a-8718-ded1370e8c96" ;
        :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.8.2 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
        :creation_date = "2020-02-12T15:38:01ZCET+0100" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.6" ;
        :institution_url = "www.smhi.se" ;
        :invar_platform_id = "-" ;
        :invar_rcm_model_driver = "MOHC-HadGEM2-ES" ;
        :invar_bc_method_id = "-" ;
        :invar_bc_observation_id = "-" ;
        :invar_bc_period = "-" ;
        :time_coverage_start = "1971" ;
        :time_coverage_end = "2000" ;
        :domain = "EUR-11" ;
        :geospatial_lat_min = "23.942343" ;
        :geospatial_lat_max = "72.641624" ;
        :geospatial_lat_resolution = "0.04268074 degree" ;
        :geospatial_lon_min = "-35.034023" ;
        :geospatial_lon_max = "73.937675" ;
        :geospatial_lon_resolution = "0.009246826 degree" ;
        :geospatial_bounds = "-" ;
        :NCO = "netCDF Operators version 4.7.7 (Homepage = http://nco.sf.net, Code = http://github.com/nco/nco)" ;
        :source = "The RCM data originate from EURO-CORDEX (Coordinated Downscaling Experiment - European Domain, EUR-11) https://euro-cordex.net/." ;
        :institution = "SMHI" ;
        :contact = "Hydro.fou@smhi.se" ;
        :references = "-" ;
        :project_id = "C3S_424_SMHI" ;
        :acknowledgements = "This work was performed within Copernicus Climate Change Service - C3S_424_SMHI, https://climate.copernicus.eu/operational-service-water-sector, on behalf of ECMWF and EU." ;
        :data_quality = "Testing of EURO-CORDEX data performed by ESGF nodes. Additional tests were performed when producing CII and ECVs in C3S_424_SMHI" ;
        :keywords = "temperature, air" ;
        :license = "Copernicus License V1.2" ;
        :output_frequency = "30 year monthly average values" ;
        :summary = "Calculated as the mean monthly values of daily mean temperature averaged over all Januaries, Februaries, etc that are part of a 30 year period." ;
        :title = "Temperature derived climate impact indicator" ;
        :comment = "The Climate Data Operators (CDO) software was used for the calculation of climate impact indicators (https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf,  https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo_eca.pdf)." ;
        :history = "CDO commands (last cdo command first and separated with ;): ymonmean; monmean" ;
        :invar_experiment_id = "historical" ;
        :invar_realisation_id = "r1i1p1" ;
        :invar_rcm_model_id = "KNMI-RACMO22E-v2" ;
        :variable_name = "tas_ymonmean" ;


Hello user131627, can you please paste a link to the data file you are trying to open, or at the very least give the name? If you have the netcdf tools installed, please paste the output of ncdump -h <your netcdf_file>. In response to your #2, the data may use so-called auxiliary coordinate variables for lat and lon, in which case lat and lon are often included as 2D arrays.

"the (x,y) in parenthesis" is telling you that that the longitude and latitude arrays are two-dimensional. In CF Convention terms, they are auxiliary coordinate variables, because the convention treats that a coordinate variable is a 1D variable with the same name as its dimension. In your example, "time" is a coordinate variable. So basically, you need to find the point on the x-y grid where the lon(x,y) and lat(x,y) values are closest to lon=89.9 and lat=-59.71. Sorry, I have no advice how to work with the data in Python, as I do all my netCDF interaction using Unidata's Java library.

Thanks. So I understand now that, for instance the lon (x,y) is two dimensional array. But is lon (x,y) saying that each lon value is taken from an x and y dimension value? e.g. if dim x = 10 and dim y = 20, then the auxiliary coordinate lon = 10,20?

More generally, I know that data can be mapped if it's provided this format (using auxiliary coordinates) -- there are tutorials that show this. But otherwise it seems like there's not easy way to access data for a lat/lon value. So, am I crazy or is this a very unhelpful way of sharing information. If the basic question you typically want to answer is "what is my variable value for this area"?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your data file is a CORDEX file for the EUR-11 domain. All CORDEX data for all domains is on a so-called rotated latitude-longitude grid. You can see the details for the EUR region here. In simple terms what this means is that the gridded netCDF data is not nicely aligned with the latitude-longitude grid. To aid in interpretation, such data sets typically include auxiliary coordinate variables for latitude and longitude that indicate for each pixel in the (x,y) grid of the data variable, here tas_ymonmean, what the exact latitude and longitude of the centre of each grid cell is.
You can identify these ACVs by the coordinates attribute in the data variable: "lat lon height". "height" is a regular 1D axis, with an netCDF variable and a dimension of the same name. "lat" and "lon" are netCDF variables that refer to dimensions x and y, also referenced by data variable tas_ymonmean, and thus ACVs. Full details here.
Your task is to interpolate these ACVs to find the grid cell closest to your location of interest. That is not trivial as it requires you to find the (x,y) indices by finding the closest point over two independent variables. To the best of my knowledge, this is something that cannot be done with the typical libraries (although I suspect xarray may support it anyway). I suggest you use the cf package, as it is the reference implementation of the CF Metadata Conventions. I do not know how to interpolate a single point on a rotated lat-long grid (or if it is even possible), but you can regrid an area like so:
import cf

# Open the file
ds = cf.read("your_cordex_file.nc")

# Access the data variable
tas = ds.select_by_identity("tas_ymonmean")

# Create your domain (area-of-interest)
dom = cf.Domain.create_regular((89, 90, 0.01), (-60, -59, 0.01))

# Regrid to a regular lat-lon grid
latlon = tas.regrids(dom, "linear")


You can now use regular interpolation techniques to find the point(s) of your interest. Given the complexity of the regridding you should create a domain that will hold all of your points of interest. If you really want only a single point I suggest you use exactly those coordinates with an additional value 0.1 degree away, then select the first point in the result.

Thanks so much for this great explanation. Two follow-ups, please: 1) Using interp2d I'm getting a 'ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid'
(looks like this has been deprecated forRegularGridInterpolator). 2) On understanding the rotated grid -- I see for CORDEX Europe (https://www.clm-community.eu/CORDEX/CMIP5/04-Europe/): "the simulations are performed on a rotated grid with the pole at 162°W longitude and 39.25°N latitude." How does this (especially the lat) 39.25 N lat make sense as a 'pole'?

Answer completely rewritten as initial answer did not consider the dependency between lat and lon. On point (2): rubberise your brain: the grid is rotated in such a way that it neatly fits the earth's surface at the area of the CORDEX domain, to minimise distortions from projecting an ellipsoid onto a "flat" grid. What is a "pole" in CORDEX is not the North Pole. Like taking a picture with your camera at an angle, you then look at the picture at the opposite angle to see everything straight again.
